# Google gmail contextual gadget - Adding custom extractor with external strings list

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets, extractor

How can I write a custom extractor which using external strings list? I want to add the contextual gadget only for dynamic limited email addresses list.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sure this isn't possible as the extractor is an XML file which compares results from parts of the email which are accessible to you to strings, regular expressions etc and can't include any scripts or custom code.

I would advise you to test the sender/receiver email against your list of addresses within the gadget_spec.xml file.

This means the gadget will always be "triggered" but you do have the option to minimize the gadget to a grey bar of about 20px(the margin around your hidden gadget, can't be edited). Or you could even display a helpful message such as "Unknown Email Address" to inform users that the gadget is working but there is nothing to display. I have come across some cases where the gadget fails to trigger on a refresh and needs to be triggered by opening a mail from the inbox, so this could help clarify this potential problem.